# While converting tweets .json file into CSV how can extract some keys and ignore unnecessary data

Tags: python, json, tweepy, tweets

I have shown a single tweet below, that all I need from is:

- text
- the time it was created at
- language
- and location in some cases.

How can I extract just these fields?

```
{
    "created_at": "Tue Dec 12 23:56:48 +0000 2017",
    "id": 940732198180872195,
    "id_str": "940732198180872195",
    "text": "if you're khoja and never heard Imran Khan during your weird high school times, what was wrong with you? lool",
    "truncated": false,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [],
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "urls": []
    },
    "metadata": {"iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent"},
    "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 728047869438078977,
        "id_str": "728047869438078977",
        "name": "Kazim Mohamed",
        "screen_name": "kmohamed313",
        "location": "",
        "description": "\u0663\u0661\u0663 // a //",
        "url": null,
        "entities": {"description": {"urls": []}},
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 1352,
        "friends_count": 880,
        "listed_count": 10,
        "created_at": "Thu May 05 02:25:13 +0000 2016",
        "favourites_count": 5472,
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "verified": false,
        "statuses_count": 20493,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "000000",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939196888292646912/BekCH3lo_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/939196888292646912/BekCH3lo_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/728047869438078977/1513462067",
        "profile_link_color": "7FDBB6",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "profile_use_background_image": false,
        "has_extended_profile": true,
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": false,
        "follow_request_sent": false,
        "notifications": false,
        "translator_type": "none"
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "lang": "en"
}
```

Comment: Parse the json and take the useful parts.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and format your question so that it's readable. Then show us what you have tried and where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Faced Similar problem a few days back. Solved it using this:

```
import pandas as pd
#results is the JSON tweet data. 

#Define the columns you want to extract
resultFrame = pd.DataFrame(columns=["username","created_at","tweet"])
print len(results)

for i in range(len(results)):
    resultFrame.loc[i,"username"] = results[i].user.screen_name
    resultFrame.loc[i, "created_at"] = results[i].created_at
    resultFrame.loc[i, "tweet"] = results[i].text
```

Comment: It is not working either. I have tried every single code on the internet but it is not working. I want to write these columns into a excel file after extracting from json. Do you have any idea about that brahh!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with each tweet

```
# line = the_tweet

data = json.loads(line)

with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
    print(data['text']+ ',' data['created_at'] + ',' + data['lang'] + ',' + data['location'], file = f)
```

[EDIT] A more scalable approach:

```
data_list.append(data['text'])
data_list.append(data['created_at'])
data_list.append(data['lang'])
data_list.append(data['location'])

import csv

with open('out.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(data_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extract that data using a dict [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) like:

#### Code:

```
sub_data = {k: data[k] for k in ('text', 'created_at', 'lang',)}
sub_data['user_location'] = data['user']['location']
```

#### Test Code:

```
import json
data = json.loads("""
    {
        "created_at": "Tue Dec 12 23:56:48 +0000 2017",
        "id": 940732198180872195,
        "id_str": "940732198180872195",
        "text": "if you're khoja and never heard Imran Khan during your weird high school times, what was wrong with you? lool",
        "truncated": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 728047869438078977,
            "id_str": "728047869438078977",
            "name": "Kazim Mohamed",
            "screen_name": "kmohamed313",
            "location": "",
        },
        "retweet_count": 0,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "favorited": false,
        "lang": "en"
    }
""")

sub_data = {k: data[k] for k in ('text', 'created_at', 'lang',)}
sub_data['user_location'] = data['user']['location']
print(sub_data)
```

#### Results:

```
{
    'text': "if you're khoja and never heard Imran Khan during your weird high school times, what was wrong with you? lool", 
    'created_at': 'Tue Dec 12 23:56:48 +0000 2017', 
    'lang': 'en', 
    'user_location': ''
}
```

Comment: data = json.load('Imran/Imran_2017-12-12.json')
sub_data = {k: data[k] for k in ('text', 'created_at', 'lang')}
sub_data['user_location'] = data['user']['location']
print(sub_data)... I'm gettin this error as you can see i'm trying to read frm json file. ->  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: That would be why it is under the *test code* heading.  You will need to change to make it work in your environment.  The code to answer the question is under *code*

Comment: It is not working. I have tried every single code on the internet but it is not working. I want to write these columns into a excel file after extracting from json. Do you have any idea about that brahh!